# Apache host header proxy

Tags: apache, hostheaders

I have multiple urls coming into a server.  I want to user host headers to redirect the traffic.  I am trying to use Apache to redirect these requests to various servers that are inside our firewall.  I have gotten part of the solution, but, I seem to be missing something.

For example, http://hostHeader1.mycompany.com should be redirected to a server inside our firewall that handles requests for hostHeader1, and the result should be handed back to the client.  http://hostHeader2.mycompany.com should be redirected to a server inside our firewall that handles requests for hostHeader2.  Etc.

Right now, I have the following, but, it redirects all traffic to http://hostHeader1Handler/:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://hostHeader1Handler/
ProxyPassReverse / http://hostHeader1Handler/
ServerName hostHeader1.mycompany.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help appreciated.

Scott

Comment: Turns out to be easier than I was making it.  Just put this in your httpd.conf:
    `RewriteEngine On`
    `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hostHeader1\.mycompany\.com$ [NC]` 
    `RewriteRule (.*) http://internalServerNameOrIP$1 [P]` 

Scott

Comment: Don't use rewrite rules for this! Virtual hosts are intended for just what you're trying to do. See @bitcloud 's answer and expand on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably your first or your only virtual host. Just add another virtual host before. Then this should be the new default.

```
NameVirtualHost *:*
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ServerName your.default.domain.de
DocumentRoot /var/www/pathToHTML
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://hostHeader1Handler/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://hostHeader1Handler/
    ServerName hostHeader1.mycompany.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The OP would probably need to add 
`<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPass / http://hostHeader2Handler/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://hostHeader2Handler/
    ServerName hostHeader2.mycompany.com
</VirtualHost>`

And i don't think you want `ProxyPreserveHost` in this case.